# MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP.6.0 cannot send in Excel VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I have an Excel project that uses the following code:

```
Dim xDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim xHTTP As ServerXMLHTTP60

Set xDoc = New DOMDocument60
If xDoc.loadXML(sSOAPRequest) Then
    Set xHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.SERVERXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xHTTP.Open "POST", Login.sRequest, False
    // - some xHTTP.setRequestHeader statements -
    xHTTP.send xDoc.xml
    // - other checks for responses from xHTTP object -
End If
```

This project has been running for months, but the other day I began getting errors from it when it would hit the "xHTTP.send" command, stating

> Error number: -2147012894. The operation timed out.
>
> No response from server. Login information cleared.
>
> The XML string contains invalid character(s).

I'm fairly certain the XML file (which gets made inside of the tool based on values entered into the Excel sheet) doesn't contain any invalid characters, as this runs the same process on the same-structured data day after day.

At first I was thinking that perhaps a reference had fallen off of the project, but it is referencing the "Microsoft XML 6.0" library in Office 2013 on Windows10.

Are there any suggestions for what else might cause this or other steps I can take to troubleshoot this kind of issue?

Comment: a server side change invalidating your existing set-up?

Comment: This was something else I was wondering as well. I'm currently trying to find some visibility into that but figured I'd see what other suggestions might be available

Comment: You might  be able to use Postman or some such to do post and examine what is going on?

Comment: Well, I didn't write the app, nor am I necessarily proficient in understanding exactly how to work with XML in VBA with these HTTP requests. Would it be possible for you to post an example of what you had in mind in an answer?

Comment: It would be useful to post more of the code.  Kind of difficult to debug without more information though.  Try running an http debugging tool like Fiddler when you send the request and see what you get.